# Vertically align 2 different font sizes to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I've set the parent as a table and children as table cells and vertically aligned to the bottom. Yet still it's showing larger font as it would be aligned to the middle

The html

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="tablecell tablecell1">7.1</div>
  <div class="tablecell tablecell2">Inches</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {width:200px; display:table;}
.tablecell {display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;}
.tablecell1 {font-size:40px;}
.tablecell2 {padding-left:15px; font-size:20px;}
```

and jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/12qmna8y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: baseline` instead or you could completely remove the `vertical-align` property, since the default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`.

`vertical-align: text-bottom` will also work.

```css
.table {
  width: 200px;
  display: table;
}
.tablecell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.tablecell1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.tablecell2 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tablecell tablecell1">7.1</div>
  <div class="tablecell tablecell2">Inches</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Such a noob :( totally forgot about baseline. I can accept answer in 10 mins and will do as soon as i can. Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up, this only works if both pieces of content are only one line and if the height of the table-cell is dictated by that one-line content: http://jsfiddle.net/vvv3a372/

Comment: @JesseKernaghan - In that case, the OP will have to change the `line-height` for the bigger `font-size`  ----> http://jsfiddle.net/vvv3a372/1/. Anyway, I don't think there will be any multi-line text in this case since the OP is just using it for numbers and units.